# PHP 5.2.12-nts with IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php, windows-server-2012-r2

After migrating the PHP 5.2.12-nts form Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 R2, all the php files with "mssql_connect" doesn't work. The error logs keep saying below.

**[05-Oct-2016 01:23:09] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0
[05-Oct-2016 01:23:09] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_pdo_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0**

The dlls can be found in the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext' directory. I have no idea why they cannot be found. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: If php claims the files are not there, then it cannot see them. We cannot tell you why. Maybe a permission issue. But please allow a side note: _why_ does one want to port a system and stay with a totally outdated and unsafe php version?

Comment: @arkascha This is a long story.... I am not the owner of this system. What I got is to migrate this system onto a Windows 2012 R2 platform from Windows 2003 which is end of support. There are many dependencies from other system to this. If we upgraded the PHP version, other systems need to be upgraded also but those developers, my boss and the system owner as well, seem unwilling to upgrade the system.....

Comment: Can't see what is "long" in that story, it simply is an extremely naive decision: what sense is there in upgrading the OS to keep it in support (has anyone _ever_ used the MS support? I _Never_ even got an answer from them...) but then _again_ install software on it that is known to have wide spread security holes that allow to take over that system? Also I do not see why "other systems need to be upgraded also"? Why should that be required if you only upgrade php-5.2 to php-5.6? That should be a drop in replacement. Sounds more like naivité to me...

Comment: You cannot see "long" as I didn't state out all the things happened here, There are many hidden systems (to me and my department) referencing to this system and those developers claimed that the upgrade of PHP 5.2.12 will make their systems malfunction. I know this is bullshit for not upgrading but the culture here is my department (IT) cannot touch and even know those hidden systems. That's why i am still keeping PHP 5.2.12 on Windows Server 2012 R2. If Windows Server 2012 R2 is really incompatible to PHP 5.2.12, I have a strong reason to upgrade the PHP or ignore this migration.

Comment: Ok,sure, I certainly didnt want to deny that there might be reasons forcing your decision... Sounds like you have to work in an organization with an unbelievable slow adaptation speed. I have seen such situations too, fortunately I turned away :-)